# Using PHP, how do I get the first paragraph of a Wikipedia article with the MediaWiki API?

Tags: php, curl, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

How do I use `PHP` to get the first paragraph of any article from Wikipedia through their MediaWiki API?

I am open to all suggestions. Most probably `CURL` or `XML` will come in handy.

Comment: What makes you think this is trivially possible? As far as I'm aware, there's nothing in the API about first paragraphs...

Comment: The problem you have isn't an issue with Wikipedia, but working with the result you get back.  You should create a new question with the example page text/data, asking how to parse out just the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the API as so:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Stack_overflow&format=xml&prop=text&section=0
```

This will return an xml file with structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <parse title="Article Title">
    <text xml:space="preserve">Text you wanted goes here</text>
  </parse>
</api>
```

Note the variables: `page=Article_Title_Goes_Here` `format=xml` `prop=text`

Comment: is there a way to skip all the extra content and just get the first intro para of the page. i seem to be geting the image and the right side tabular details etc

Answer (score -3):

I would use `file_get_contents('http://wikipedia.com/'.$rest_of_url)`

Then just use string parsing to select everything form

to

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: it escaped:   use string parsing to select everything between the first `<p>` and `</p>` using `substr`